# Как создать обводку на тексте внутри QPushButton

Tags: python, pyqt5, qss, qpushbutton, paintevent

Мне нужен способ, при котором на любом цвете кнопки можно было прочитать текст этой кнопки. 
Цвета задаются не статически (не прописаны в коде), а пользователем. Потому возможны ситуации когда например на чёрный текст будет приходится тёмно-синий цвет и наоборот, на белый текст, яркие цвета.

Установить прозрачность через `rgba` тоже не вариант, цвет задаётся в HEX-формате. Потому как вариант - прописать обводку для текста.

`border-color` через `setStyleSheet` почему то не работает.

Так же пробовал через `QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect`, но в таком случае тень накладывается только на саму кнопку, а не на текст. 
Гугл только про обводку QLabel подсказывает. Помогите с решением.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class WinFrame(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.win = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.win.setObjectName("page_video")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.win)

        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.win)
        userColor = 'e5ff70'
        self.tag = QPushButton("Рандомная кнопка")
        self.tag.setStyleSheet(
            f"background-color: #{userColor}; color: white; border-color: black;")
        shadow = QtWidgets.QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(
            self, blurRadius=14.0, color=QColor("#a8a7a7"), offset=QtCore.QPointF(0.0, 0.0))
        self.tag.setGraphicsEffect(shadow)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tag)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WinFrame()
    window.show()
    window.resize(800, 600)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import sys, math
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *


class PushButton(QPushButton):
    def __init__(self, userColor, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.w = 1 / 25
        self.mode = True
        self.setBrush(Qt.white)
        self.setPen(Qt.black)
        self.userColor = userColor

    def scaledOutlineMode(self):
        return self.mode

    def setScaledOutlineMode(self, state):
        self.mode = state

    def outlineThickness(self):
        return self.w * self.font().pointSize() if self.mode else self.w

    def setOutlineThickness(self, value):
        self.w = value

    def setBrush(self, brush):
        if not isinstance(brush, QBrush):
            brush = QBrush(brush)
        self.brush = brush

    def setPen(self, pen):
        if not isinstance(pen, QPen):
            pen = QPen(pen)
        pen.setJoinStyle(Qt.RoundJoin)
        self.pen = pen

    def sizeHint(self):
        w = math.ceil(self.outlineThickness() * 2)
        return super().sizeHint() + QSize(w, w)
    
    def minimumSizeHint(self):
        w = math.ceil(self.outlineThickness() * 2)
        return super().minimumSizeHint() + QSize(w, w)
    
    def paintEvent(self, event):
        w = self.outlineThickness()
        rect = self.rect()
        metrics = QFontMetrics(self.font())
        tr = metrics.boundingRect(self.text()).adjusted(0, 0, w, w)
        
        if self.width(): 
            indent = (metrics.boundingRect('x').width() + w * 2) / 2
        else:
            indent = w

        x = (rect.width() - tr.width()) / 2
        y = (rect.height() + metrics.ascent() - metrics.descent()) / 2
        
        path = QPainterPath()
        path.addText(x, y, self.font(), self.text())
        qp = QPainter(self)
        qp.setRenderHint(QPainter.Antialiasing)

        qp.setPen(Qt.blue)
        qp.setBrush(QColor(f'#{self.userColor}'))
        rectf = QRectF(rect)
        qp.drawRoundedRect(rectf, 6, 6)

        self.pen.setWidthF(w * 2)
        qp.strokePath(path, self.pen)
        if 1 < self.brush.style() < 15:
            qp.fillPath(path, self.palette().window())
        qp.fillPath(path, self.brush)
        

class WinFrame(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        userColor = 'e5ff70'

        button = PushButton(userColor, 'Рандомная кнопка')
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: print(f'{button.text()}')) 
        button.setStyleSheet('font-family: Zapfino; font-size: 70pt')

# попробуйте раскомментировть строку ниже
#        button.setBrush(QColor(f'#{userColor}'))
        
        vbox = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)        
        vbox.addWidget(button)
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = WinFrame()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю! Вариант подошёл

Comment: @PandaStock я рад что у вас все получилось.